# How to customize fileupload.js when using primefaces?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to access data variable of fileupload.js so that i can add additional logic. Let say when the file is uploading, i want to grab the data value so that i can show the progress status in a different way. Is this can be achieved? Appreciate your time to answer this question.

Comment: Yes this can be achieved.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get progress for individual files you can use callbacks provided by the plugin,
as you mentioned you are using fileupload.js means you are using bluimp file upload plugin.

it provides many callbacks

eg

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadprogress', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
```

here's the link to find all the [options](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options) provided by blueimp plugin. if you are not using this plugin then never mind.

Comment: Did you see I mentioned primefaces?

Comment: here http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/javax.faces.resource/fileupload/fileupload.js.jsf?ln=primefaces it internally uses "bluimp" search for it.

Comment: is #fileupload is input type or div?